# Htaccess regex that redirects a particular pattern to the homepage

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use a regex to redirect queries that contain `/page/` **and** `?lang=xx` **or** `&lang=xx` to the homepage.

This is what I've tried so far, the first part of the rule works but not the one with the `?lang=` and `&lang=` after the first question mark.

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?(\?|&)lang=([a-z]{2})$ https://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/?(\?|&)lang=([a-z]{2})$ https://example.com [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` directive matches against the URL-path only. To match the query string you need to match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a preceding *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=[a-z]{2}(&|$)
RewriteRule ^page/\d+/?$ https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You've not stated the actual URLs you are trying to match, so based on your rule, this will match URLs of the form `/page/<number>/`, where the trailing slash is optional. Plus the `lang` URL parameter must be present anywhere in the query string and the value of which must be two letters. If the `lang` URL parameter is present, but is *empty* or contains more than two letters then it won't match and no redirect occurs.

`\d` is a shorthand character class that is the same as `[0-9]`. The capturing subgroups that you had in your original rule are not required.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. Ensure your browser cache is cleared before testing.